# My behaviourSubject is returning null on load of a page in angular 9, it is not updating with current value

Tags: rxjs, angular9

Onlogout() I am making the userSubject.next(null). So while logging in it is taking the null value first and only after refresh of the page it is taking the updated user value.
please can anyone suggest if I am missing anything, or the best way to update the behaviourSubject on load of the page. please find the code below.

```js
/* In login Service*/
//in the constructor
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')));
    this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }
  
   public get userValue(): User {
    return this.userSubject.value;
  }
  
//in login method to get user details
 login(username, password) {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${environment.apiUrl}/v1/login`, { username, password })
      .pipe(map(user => {
        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes        
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        console.log("inisde usersubjec====>", this.userSubject);
      this.userSubject.next(user);

        return user;
      }));
  }
  
 //logout method
 logOutUser() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('user');    
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/tag/v1/logout`, null).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("inside logOutUser method:UserValue==>", this.user);
      this.userSubject.next(null);
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    );}

/*In login component ts */
onSubmit() {
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    };
    this.loginService.login(this.getformControls().username.value, this.getformControls().password.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("User Logged in Data==>", data);
          this.router.navigate(['/homepage']);
        }
      );
  }
```

So after post call, getting the user details and updates the behaviourSubject and then navigate to homepage. But on landing to homepage the userValue is being null and not the updated value. Only after refreshing the homepage it is getting the updated value. Please suggest how can I get the update uservalue in homepage on landing itself without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor try to make the `JSON.parse` more safe as the `getItem` might be null at the beginning, second thing try to use `this.user` and use `async` with it in the template and it will give you the latest value from the `BehaviorSubject`, `.value` from BehaviorSubject doesn't give you the latest emitted value.

I recommend you if you can provide a `stackblitz` it will be great.

Comment: JSON.parse more safe means please. I didn't get you and where you are asking me to use this.user and async please? If .value won't give me the latest emitted value then What I can use please?

Comment: I mean in the place you are using the `useValue` instead use `this.user` like this -> `this.user.subscribe` and this will give you the latest value & if you are using this `useValue` in the template to show the user data use `this.user` like this in template `user | async as userData` this will work perfectly fine and if you can provide a stackblitz it will be great

Comment: To provide with stackblitz code backedn service call configuration should be right?and 
you want me to right like wise right?
public get userValue(): User {
    return this.user.subscribe;
  }.??? but it is throwing error

Comment: make it like this `useValue() { return this.user }` and then use it as I told you in the last comment